# "uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rb_Support (NameError)" when running Cucumber for Ruby & Watir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, watir

After installing Ruby, Cucumber and Watir using gem I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rb_Support (NameError)
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:41:in `constantize_name'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:13:in `block in constantize'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:12:in `each'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:12:in `constantize'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:87:in `load_programming_language'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:242:in `programming_language_for'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:226:in `load_file'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:97:in `block in load_files!'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in `each'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:96:in `load_files!'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:242:in `load_step_definitions'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:38:in `execute!'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
W:/Programme/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'**
```

Anyone got any idea why this is not working?
I copied the exact example from the github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself.

If anyone runs into this problem it is most likely caused by Ruby versions that are not compatible with Gherkin/Cucumber and/or Watir.

Although there are newer version of Ruby, the only versions that worked on my Windows 7 (Win64) machine were a combination of:

- Ruby: rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p645.exe
- DevKit: DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

Then I followed the installation instructions on http://www.spritecloud.com/2015/04/complete-setup-guide-for-ruby-cucumber-and-watir-on-windows/

And I used the example on https://github.com/spriteCloud/cucumber-watir-example which worked.

Following this did not create any errors and the example worked.

Good luck!